# Sequence in local cohomology for multiple closed subsets

Tags: gn.general-topology, cohomology, local-cohomology

Let $X$ be topological space with closed subsets $A,B,C \subset X$ and $\mathcal{F} \in Sh(X)$.

I'm trying to understand
\begin{equation*}
H^i_{A\cap B}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{A\cap C}(X,\mathcal{F})\oplus H^i_{B\cap C}(X,\mathcal{F})  \rightarrow H^i_{A}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{B}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{C}(X,\mathcal{F}),
\end{equation*}
where the morphism are the ones coming from the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for local cohomology.

Exists there an exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
H^i_{A\cap B\cap C}(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow H^i_{A\cap B}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{A\cap C}(X,\mathcal{F})\oplus H^i_{B\cap C}(X,\mathcal{F} \rightarrow H^i_{A}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{B}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{C}(X,\mathcal{F}) 
\end{equation*}
or something similar that relates the local cohomology of more then two subsets?